# c++: write a char at a given char* causes segfault

Tags: c++, char, segmentation-fault

I want to copy a char to an address where a given char* points to.

it's in a function which is called by main:

```
char data = "       ";
myfunction(data, somethingelse);
...
```

inside the function i have something like

```
void myfunction(char* data, short somethingelse) {
...
char byte = 0;
inputfilestream.read(&byte, 1);
*data = byte; // here i get the segfault
data++;
...
}
```

the segfault also comes when i to the copy using strncpy:

```
strncpy(data, byte, 1);
```

why is there a segfault? data isn't const and the address where i actually write to is exactly the same as the one where i allocated the data-array. i've tested that multiple times.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile : `char data = "       ";`

Comment: char data = "       "; - did you mean char[] data = "        "; ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String literals are readonly. If you want a modifyable string, you must use an array, e.g.:

```
char data[10];
```

Or:

```
char *data = new char[10];
```

To elaborate a bit more: the type of a string literal is actually `const char*`. Assigning a string literal to a non-const `char*` is therefore technically invalid, but most compilers allow it anyway for legacy reasons. Many modern compilers will at least issue a warning when you try to do that.

Answer (score 3):

`data` is assigned a string literal. String literals are ready only, and writing to them will cause segfaults.

Try this:

```
char data[10]; // or whatever size you want.
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

> why is there a segfault? data isn't const and the address where i actually write to is exactly the same as the one where i allocated the data-array.

You didn't allocate anything. `char *data = "         ";` shouldn't even compile in C++. You are assigning a constant string to a non-constant.

Comment: my mistake. i actually wrote 
char *data = "    ";
but thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I can never understand why people re-type code - copy and paste has been around for 30 years - why do some people not use it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
char byte = 0;
inputfilestream.read(&byte, 1);
*data = byte; // here i get the segfault
data++; // << How many times?
```

No problem

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *data = "Yello"; // or char data[] = "Yello";
    *data = 'H';
    puts(data); // Hello
}
```